# How can I solve/suppress DeadObjectException in Xamarin.Forms Map

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin

An Android Xamarin app that I'm working on has reported an error with the following callstack through App Center:

```
android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative Binder.java
android.os.BinderProxy.transact Binder.java:503
android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.bindService ActivityManagerNative.java:4509
android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon ContextImpl.java:1432
android.app.ContextImpl.bindService ContextImpl.java:1395
android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService ContextWrapper.java:632
jd.b :com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@202414044@20.24.14 (040300-0):10
im.a :com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@202414044@20.24.14 (040300-0):23
im.a :com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@202414044@20.24.14 (040300-0):40
he.h :com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@202414044@20.24.14 (040300-0):26
hi.handleMessage :com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@202414044@20.24.14 (040300-0):50
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage Handler.java:98
android.os.Looper.loop Looper.java:158
android.os.HandlerThread.run HandlerThread.java:61
```

I've never seen this error myself, but I believe it is caused by Google Maps as implied by:

`com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite...`

My app uses the Xamarin Forms Map class: `Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Map`.

Since I don't know how to reproduce this (it's quite rare), and since I don't see any of my own code in the callstack (it all seems to be inner java calls) is there a way to diagnose this problem further, or to suppress the error somehow?

According to App Center, this is causing a crash on our app. Since maps are not critical to our app (just a convenience), I'd rather have a missing map than a crash, so even high-level suppression of the error is okay.

Is there a way I can figure out what might be causing the error? Is there a way to suppress it or solve the underlying problem?

Answer (score 0):

I would use AppCenter's LogFlow and log all the parameters that go into your maps part. That way, when a crash happens, you can see which parameters went into it and you might be able to reproduce it.
Since it is an external API, I would also look for errors in Google Maps console, and also check if you were hitting any limits on your Google Maps plan.